# Determine from terminal in xfce if the user is switching the active window

Tags: bash, terminal, xfce

I am trying to implement a keyboard shortcut so that I can switch between only a filtered list of windows (only windows of a particular application) in xfce4. I want do that by hiding undesired windows and then using the normal window selection mechanism (using alt+tab) to select a window from the remaining windows.

Filtering and hiding works fine. Within my shortcut I use `xdotool` to fake the pressing of `alt+tab` and the windows selection is starting. But I don't know how within my script I can determine if the window selection is done. Because afterwards I need to un-hide the windows excluded from within the selection.

Is there a process or a window id or something else that can be used to determine if the window selection process is still active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this works in your script, but I understood that normally a
user holds <kbd>alt</kbd> down and uses <kbd>tab</kbd> to choose a window,
then releases <kbd>alt</kbd>. If that is the case, then you could use the
release of the key to determine end of selection.

You can monitor X11 keyboard events in several ways, one of which is with
`xinput --test-xi2 --root`. This outputs several lines for each event; for
example when I release <kbd>Meta_R</kbd> which implements alt on my
keyboard, I get:

```
EVENT type 14 (RawKeyRelease)
    device: 3 (9)
    detail: 105
...
EVENT type 3 (KeyRelease)
    device: 9 (9)
    detail: 105
...
    modifiers: locked 0 latched 0 base 0x9 effective: 0x8
```

The salient points here are the *detail* which is the keycode of the key,
and the *effective modifiers*, a bitmask of which shift keys were down just
before the event; it is 0x8 as this corresponds to `mod1`. So you can just
look for an event where the modifiers are 0, or a KeyRelease or
RawKeyRelease with detail 105 (in my case). You can find the keycode by
testing, or from `xmodmap -pk` and `xmodmap -pm`.

The following works for me, exiting when <kbd>alt</kbd> is not pressed, or released.

```bash
sed -n '
 /modifiers:.* 0$/q
 /KeyRelease/{n;n;/ 105$/q}
' < <(xinput --test-xi2 --root)
```

Note the use of bash's process substitution `<()`. Using a pipe instead
causes the script to wait for the pipeline to finish, which `xinput` does
only on a later event when it gets a SIGPIPE.

Comment: Hi Meuh! Perfect, thank you very much. Yes, this output of `xinput` solves my issue! Geat!!